# Change variable type in netlogo

Tags: variables, dynamic, directory, netlogo

I have a problem that I want to change list item and/or integer type variable into string in order to compare the value:

```
item n fileList = "#NULL!"
```

And also to make dynamic directory:

```
csv:to-file "/eksport/" + any_variable_not_string + "my-matrix.csv" export-mylist
```

Comment: See the `word` reporter primitive.

Comment: I know stack says that thank you comments are not allowed or not recommended but this fixed so many problems I had, so thanks (and as always in coding the solution is very simple).